# Single API with Multiple Applications

Tags: rest

I'm working through a project redesign conceptually and am struggling with whether an approach makes sense. So as not avoid *opinions* and *open-ended discussion* I will try to be as specific as I can.

We have several web applications (5+) which are each considered a **product**. They are related and share similar data -- even to the point where a user in App1 should be able to reference or import his/her data from App2. In my mind, it logically makes sense to have a single REST API which acts as a layer between the data model and the several applications. In this way, changes can be made at the API Level and will work in all the applications (assume it maintains backwards compatibility).

I am trying to consider how to design this REST API to work effectively with multiple applications. Here are some of my considerations:

## Versioning

When thinking through this, I would want the API to be versioned like `api.example.com/v1` and `api.example.com/v2`. I think this is important for the future and how development progresses.

## Namespacing

This is a problem area. What if two applications use a **User** resource differently? Like there is specific processing and parameters App1 needs, but not App2? I'm sure a user is a bad example as it should be fairly standard, but I can see conflicts occurring. So do I create namespaces like this?

- api.example.com/v1/app1
- api.example.com/v1/app2

In doing something like that, I am tightly coupling the applications to the API. Perhaps a Resource Namespace ID #?

## Version + Namespace

What if I need to make major changes to the namespaced API's for App1, do I globally increment the version and now other namespaced API's are on v2 even though they did not receive changes? Should I switch the namespace and version around like this?

- api.example.com/app1/v1

## Complicated Requests

Unfortunately, due to the nature of these applications, they are extremely complex. Granted, much of what makes them that way is being refactored in this rewrite to simplify things, but we still require certain functions that do not seem to fit the rest pattern. Do method calls like this make sense?

- [GET] api.example.com/v1/app1/object1/with_object2
- [GET] api.example.com/v1/app1/object1/with_object3_and_revision_history

Those are overly generic and it's difficult to think of actual use cases off hand.

**TL;DR** How do you organize a single REST API that acts as the mediator between multiple different applications and a single data model?

Comment: In the case of a user object/class what if you create a very generic one that has parameters that EVERY user object in every application uses. Then for each app you can inherit the basic user and create an application specific object that extends functionality and parameters?